# VSTS build pipeline how to share output of a docker task?

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have a sample pipeline with a docker task where my Dockerfile executes a shell script that generates some data.

When I finally run my image how do I share output of my script from inside of the container with the next task or make it somehow available or pass further?

As I been doing further research, found some info that one possible way is to leverage build agent file system, and use copy tasks for that but not sure if this is an optimal solution for the problem if any.

[image]

Comment: Do you run the image also in the pipeline? (because I see only build and push)

Comment: Yes in the pipeline, this is just example image I took.

Comment: Can you share your full pipeline and your shell script?

Comment: With little delay but pic added

Comment: If you have a volume so try to add the output to the volume folder, than it will be exist in the agent also in the next steps.

Comment: Thx, that worked, I used $(Build.SourcesDirectory) and got my file dropped directly to build directory.

Comment: Great!! I added it also as an answer :)

Comment: @CodeHooligan ,Does the below answer could help you resolve your issue? If yes, you can accept the answer thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works. If you still facing some issues, feel free to leave comment here :-)

Comment: @Code Hooligan Since below answer is working. You can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map the volume to the build folder and put there the output.

Now it will be in the agent and you can access it in the next steps.